# AJAX not parsing data in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, oop

I'm facing an unexpected issue while sending one simple form field data to another PHP file through Ajax. I have done it a lot of time but this time I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Please help!

**Here is my form:**

```
<form action="textify.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="textify">
    <button>textify it!</button>
    <pre style="display: none;"></pre>
</form>
```

**And here this is my jQuery with AJAX:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('form').submit(function(){

         var textify = $('input[name=textify]').val();

         $.post('textify.php', {data: textify}, function(txt){
             $('pre').show();
             $('pre').text(txt);
         });

         return false;
     });
});
```

**And here is my file where I'm sending data to (textify.php)**

```
class textify
{
    function __construct() {
        $textify = $_POST['data'];
        echo $textify;
    }
}
new textify;
```

And this is the unexpected issue:

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: data in <b>C:\Users\omer\Desktop\textify\textify.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
```

Comment: Great! So what is the unexpected issue?

Comment: You have to use `$_REQUEST['data'];` instead of `$_REQUEST['text']`

Comment: @derape edit my question to show the unexpected issue...

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Sorry for the confusion. I have edit my question please check again ... I have used `$_POST['data'];`

Comment: now my dear friend you posted different code that is executed.

Comment: What is the problem after your edit?

Comment: @Omer Then please update the issue, because `$_POST['data']` cannot produce `Undefined index: text` as an error, there is nothing with text as an index in your code.

Comment: @briosheje... Updated!!! Sorry about the misunderstanding ... I pasted the code I was testing .. But now its the complete question..

Comment: Ok, now it sounds reasonable (doesn't make sense to me though, perhaps I'm used to $.ajax instead). Can you please try to `echo join(",",$_REQUEST);` ? Just to check what the php script is actually receiving.

Comment: Hahaah, free upvote for all :D

Comment: is your form inside `textify.php` ?

Comment: Please do `alert(textify);` in jquery did you get it?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi... Yes getting it

Comment: Can you show what is your **line 19**

Comment: You are using `$.post` but you have not use `event.preventDefault()` although having `submit` `event`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty simple the key name is invalid. You use keyname `data` but you get `text` which does not exists.

change

```
 $.post('textify.php', {data: textify}, function(txt){
```

to

```
 $.post('textify.php', {text: textify}, function(txt){
```

or better use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to avoid such mistakes.

**Edit:**

change code to:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('form').submit(function(ev){
         ev.preventDefault();
         $.post('textify.php', $(this).serialize(), function(txt){
             $('pre').show();
             $('pre').text(txt);
         });
     });
});
```

in PHP

```
echo $_POST['textify'];
```

Comment: Thanks Robert ... Your answer works really well but the thing is my code worked as well :) I wasn't using any local server to test it... I was using phpStorm's own php compiler which was causing this issue. Just moved my project to XAMPP htdocs and my code worked :)... But thanks for your effort

Answer (score 2):

use $_REQUEST['data'] instead of $_REQUEST['text']

```
class textify

{
    function __construct()
    {
        $textify = $_REQUEST['data']; //change text to data because you use data in ajax post.

        echo $textify;

    }
}


new textify;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make some changes `{text: textify}` instead of `{data: textify}` like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('form').submit(function(){

         var textify = $('input[name="textify"]').val();

         $.post('textify.php', {text: textify}, function(txt){
             $('pre').show();
             $('pre').text(txt);
         });

         return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: Can you review My question again... I have made some changes